# Open the iPhone camera?

Tags: objective-c

We need to open the iPhone camera, to take images that will be saved to the camera roll.

I have read many examples here that all of them opens the `UIImagePickerView`.
Besides the fact that i cant understand why i have to open the picker view in order to open the camera , i just can't do that- i dont want the picker view, because i have my costumed photo album that we build, and we just need to have a little button in it, that opens the camera to take an image . without opening any other views above it .

Is that possible to use the camera without this pickerview that will cover my scene ?
or can i lead the user to the camera app and than take him back to my app ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display camera stream in you app without `UIImagePickerController` than you should you `AVFoundation` framework.

Here some some examples and tutorials:

[take-photos-with AVFoundation](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/)

[Custom camera](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/145399/ios-module-with-custom-camera-view-using-avfoundation)

[Displaying camera](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of high level (i.e. Apple supplies the UI element) classes, you have to go to a more foundational (lower) level of API's, which would be [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/) and AVCaptureDeviceInput.

And Apple has some nice source code available [in their AVCam project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html).